# Run SlmQueue jobs with cronjob

Tags: zend-framework2

I use the zf2 module SlmQueue to queue some processes in my application.

My problem is, that I'm not able to install some systems like supervisord on my server.

Is there a way to process the jobs of a queue via cronjob? I read something about it was possible in an earlier verions of SlmQueue, but I don't know how it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different aspects: where to store messages vs how to consume messages.

If you don't have any dedicated queue system, store messages in MySQL (or flat files or any other available).

Then install a cronjob which will consume and handle messages from your job source every now and then (mutatis mutandis):

```
*/10 * * * * php public/index.php queue mysql default
```

I don't know if this command handles concurrency. If not you should write a wrapper script which will create a lock file to prevent running this command multiple times.